# Filter object ObservableCollection<Object> of some type

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have a `ObservableCollection<Object>` that holds two different types of objects: `Directory` and `File`. This collection is bound to a control and at some time, I want to filter out the `File`s.

I have the following code, which is not working:

```
var files = (from File f in (from Directory d in selectedDirs
                             select d.Childs)
             where f is File
             select f);
```

I'm getting this error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[System.Object]'
>   to type 'CMBraga_FileExplorer.File'.

How can I get my values? I know they are `File`s.

```
// this was ran without explicit conversion ( just as an example )

? myCollection
Count = 5
    [0]: {CMBraga_FileExplorer.File}
    [1]: {CMBraga_FileExplorer.File}
    [2]: {CMBraga_FileExplorer.File}
    [3]: {CMBraga_FileExplorer.File}
    [4]: {CMBraga_FileExplorer.File}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the reason you're getting the exception is because you are declaring the types of your query variable (i.e., `from File f in ...`).  By doing that, you are trying to cast the objects to the specified type.  It would appear that your types of some of the items in `d.Childs` are `ObservableCollection<Object>`.  Those are clearly not `File` objects hence the cast error.

Use the [`Enumerable.OfType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension method here to do the filtering.  This is exactly what it was made for.

```
var files = selectedDirs
    .Cast<Directory>() // this cast might not even be necessary
    .SelectMany(d => d.Childs)
    .OfType<File>(); // filter selecting only File objects
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq expression for that:

```
using System.Linq;
// ...
ObservableCollection<object> list;
// ...
IEnumerable<CMBraga_FileExplorer.File> castedList = list.Cast<CMBraga_FileExplorer.File>();
```